# Расстанoвкa зaпятых

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, верно ли расставлены запятые. Спасибо. "Ее платье, словно праздничный торт, будет белым и пышным"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, верно, так как Вы выделили запятыми сравнительный оборот

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А такой вариант верен:"Ее платье будет белым и пышным, словно праздничный торт"? Или запятая перед "словно" не нужна?

Comment: Все верно, ведь здесь  тот же сравнительный оборот, но поставлен в другую часть предложения. Если ответ Вас устроил, можете кликнуть слева "принять ответ"

Answer (score 2):

Сравнительный оборот всегда обособляется запятыми, где бы он ни находился: в начале, в середине или в конце фразы. И союз "словно" не единственный сравнительный. Может быть "как", "будто", "как будто".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!